# How to go to definition of a function in VScode using ctags (from windows to linux)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ctags, exuberant-ctags, vscode-remote

There is a big project with many parent/children directories on a Linux machine. The Exuberant CTags are installed and the tags are created using ctags. Now, I am using Visual Studio Code on Windows to load that entire directory. I have installed the relevant ctags extenions, but I cannot go to definition of some of the functions in VScode (on the Linux machine the ctags work fine in vim).

My specific questions:

1. What is the best (easiest, most efficient) way to do this (navigate through some codes that are based in Linux from Windows)?
2. How can I use the ctags, that are generated on the Linux machine, on windows?

P.S.: I think I should add some directories to my windows path or include path ...